# Bash Arithmetic $number != $((number))

Tags: bash

When trying to execute a simple bash script to increment a number with preceding 0's by 1, the original number is interpreted incorrectly.

```
#!/bin/bash
number=0026
echo $number
echo $((number))
echo $((number+1))
```

When this command is executed I get the output:

```
0026
22
23
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: leading `0` means it's an octal number, octal(26) = decimal(22)

Comment: using printf vs echo would have helped you spot this easier - printf "%d" 0026

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To force base-10 representation:

```
$ echo $((10#$number))
26
$ echo $((10#$number + 1))
27
```

---

Responding to kojiro's comment:

```
$ something=08
$ echo $((something))
bash: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
$ echo $(($something))
bash: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
$ echo $((10#something))
bash: 10#something: value too great for base (error token is "10#something")
$ echo $((10#$something))
8
$ echo $((08))
bash: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
$ echo $((10#08))
8

$ echo $(( 16#10 ))
16
$ echo $(( 16#f ))
15
$ echo $(( 16#10 - 1 ))
15
```

Comment: That's a new one for me.  Thanks, Glenn!  :)

Comment: I think this statement is a little confusing, actually. `echo $(( something ))` will *always* give base-10 representation. What the "radix#repr" expression gives you is control over the _interpretation_ of the expansion. `echo $(( 16#10 ))` doesn't print out "f", which would be the base-16 _representation_ of that number; it prints out "10", which is the base-10 _representation_ of the given number that was interpreted as base-16.

Comment: @kojiro, what? I've provided some examples above. The expression `16#10` is the decimal value 16: `echo $(( 16#10 - 1 ))` outputs 15

Comment: @glennjackman - @kojiro isn't disagreeing with you.  They mean that the *output* of `$(( ... ))` is always base-10.  The `radix#expr` form simply changes how it interprets the *input*.  I think they were supplying additional information.